# Hiding API Keys on GitHub in the existing commit

Tags: git, github

I have a private project on github. It has file commits that contain API keys. I want to make my project public, but not show my keys. Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Comment: There is no way of hiding private data. You should use env variables to include keys/passwords.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+remove+sensitive+data